# AndEngine sprite moving

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

I have a problem with moving sprites. I attached the `onAreaTouch()` event to several sprites. In this event there are two more events. First, `isActionMove()` and second `isActionUp()`.

When I drag a sprite, if it passes through the other one, the event leaves the sprite and starts to drag the other one. How can I avoid this?

If I make a fast drag and up, `isActionUp()` method is not working, but if I make a slow drag and up, `isActionUp()` method is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

before returning scene object from onCreateScene() method.